# Fail2ban is not banning IP

Tags: centos7, dovecot, fail2ban

Software:
Centos 7 (with firewallD)
fail2ban 0.9.5
dovecot 2.2.10

I am trying to setup fail2ban on my mailserver, to secure it from brute force login through imap (dovecot).
Right now i'm stuck, and fail2ban still doesn't work, below are my config files:

in /var/log/fail2ban.log

```
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,110 fail2ban.server         [3712]: INFO    Exiting Fail2ban
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,306 fail2ban.server         [4080]: INFO    Changed logging target to /var/log/fail2ban.log for Fail2ban v0.9.5
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,306 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dbfile', '/var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,307 fail2ban.database       [4080]: INFO    Connected to fail2ban persistent database '/var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3'
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,309 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dbpurgeage', '86400']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,310 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['add', 'dovecot', 'systemd']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,310 fail2ban.jail           [4080]: INFO    Creating new jail 'dovecot'
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,335 fail2ban.jail           [4080]: INFO    Jail 'dovecot' uses systemd
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,335 fail2ban.filter         [4080]: DEBUG   Setting usedns = warn for FilterSystemd(Jail('dovecot'))
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,361 fail2ban.filter         [4080]: DEBUG   Created FilterSystemd(Jail('dovecot'))
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,362 fail2ban.filtersystemd  [4080]: DEBUG   Created FilterSystemd
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,362 fail2ban.jail           [4080]: INFO    Initiated 'systemd' backend
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,363 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'usedns', 'warn']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,363 fail2ban.filter         [4080]: DEBUG   Setting usedns = warn for FilterSystemd(Jail('dovecot'))
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,364 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'maxretry', '1']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,364 fail2ban.filter         [4080]: INFO    Set maxRetry = 1
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,364 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'addignoreip', '127.0.0.1/8']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,364 fail2ban.filter         [4080]: DEBUG   Add 127.0.0.1/8 to ignore list
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,365 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'logencoding', 'auto']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,366 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'bantime', '60000']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,366 fail2ban.actions        [4080]: INFO    Set banTime = 60000
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,366 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'ignorecommand', '']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,367 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'findtime', '60000']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,367 fail2ban.filter         [4080]: INFO    Set findtime = 60000
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,368 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'addfailregex', 'auth-worker\\(\\S*\\): Info: sql\\(\\S*,<HOST>\\): Password mismatch\\s*$']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,369 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'addfailregex', 'auth-worker\\(\\S*\\): Info: sql\\(\\S*,<HOST>\\): unknown user\\s*$']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,371 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'addfailregex', '# ^(?:\\[\\])?\\s*(?:<[^.]+ [^.]+>\\s+)?(?:\\S+\\s+)?(?:kernel: \\[ *\\d+\\.\\d+\\]\\s+)?(?:@vserver_\\S+\\s+)?(?:(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?(auth|dovecot(-auth)?|auth-worker)(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?(auth|dovecot(-auth)?|auth-worker)(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)\\s+)?(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\]\\s+)?(pam_unix(\\(dovecot:auth\\))?:)?\\s+authentication failure; logname=\\S* uid=\\S* euid=\\S* tty=dovecot ruser=\\S* rhost=<HOST>(\\s+user=\\S*)?\\s*$']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,376 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'addfailregex', '# ^(?:\\[\\])?\\s*(?:<[^.]+ [^.]+>\\s+)?(?:\\S+\\s+)?(?:kernel: \\[ *\\d+\\.\\d+\\]\\s+)?(?:@vserver_\\S+\\s+)?(?:(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?(auth|dovecot(-auth)?|auth-worker)(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?(auth|dovecot(-auth)?|auth-worker)(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)\\s+)?(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\]\\s+)?(pop3|imap)-login: (Info: )?(Aborted login|Disconnected)(: Inactivity)? \\(((auth failed, \\d+ attempts)( in \\d+ secs)?|tried to use (disabled|disallowed) \\S+ auth)\\):( user=<\\S*>,)?( method=\\S+,)? rip=<HOST>(, lip=(\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3})?(, TLS( handshaking(: SSL_accept\\(\\) failed: error:[\\dA-F]+:SSL routines:[TLS\\d]+_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol)?)?(: Disconnected)?)?(, session=<\\S+>)?\\s*$']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,384 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'addfailregex', '# ^(?:\\[\\])?\\s*(?:<[^.]+ [^.]+>\\s+)?(?:\\S+\\s+)?(?:kernel: \\[ *\\d+\\.\\d+\\]\\s+)?(?:@vserver_\\S+\\s+)?(?:(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?(auth|dovecot(-auth)?|auth-worker)(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?(auth|dovecot(-auth)?|auth-worker)(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)\\s+)?(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\]\\s+)?(Info|dovecot: auth\\(default\\)|auth-worker\\(\\d+\\)): pam\\(\\S+,<HOST>\\): pam_authenticate\\(\\) failed: (User not known to the underlying authentication module: \\d+ Time\\(s\\)|Authentication failure \\(password mismatch\\?\\))\\s*$']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,391 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'addfailregex', '# ^(?:\\[\\])?\\s*(?:<[^.]+ [^.]+>\\s+)?(?:\\S+\\s+)?(?:kernel: \\[ *\\d+\\.\\d+\\]\\s+)?(?:@vserver_\\S+\\s+)?(?:(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?(auth|dovecot(-auth)?|auth-worker)(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?(auth|dovecot(-auth)?|auth-worker)(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)\\s+)?(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\]\\s+)?(auth|auth-worker\\(\\d+\\)): (pam|passwd-file)\\(\\S+,<HOST>\\): unknown user\\s*$']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,399 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'addfailregex', '# ^(?:\\[\\])?\\s*(?:<[^.]+ [^.]+>\\s+)?(?:\\S+\\s+)?(?:kernel: \\[ *\\d+\\.\\d+\\]\\s+)?(?:@vserver_\\S+\\s+)?(?:(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?(auth|dovecot(-auth)?|auth-worker)(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?(auth|dovecot(-auth)?|auth-worker)(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)\\s+)?(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\]\\s+)?(auth|auth-worker\\(\\d+\\)): Info: ldap\\(\\S*,<HOST>,\\S*\\): invalid credentials\\s*$']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,405 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'addfailregex', '# ^(?:\\[\\])?\\s*(?:<[^.]+ [^.]+>\\s+)?(?:\\S+\\s+)?(?:kernel: \\[ *\\d+\\.\\d+\\]\\s+)?(?:@vserver_\\S+\\s+)?(?:(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?(auth|dovecot(-auth)?|auth-worker)(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?(auth|dovecot(-auth)?|auth-worker)(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)\\s+)?(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\]\\s+)?(auth|auth-worker\\(\\d+\\)): Info: sql\\(\\S*,<HOST>\\): unknown user\\s*$']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,412 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'addfailregex', '# ^(?:\\[\\])?\\s*(?:<[^.]+ [^.]+>\\s+)?(?:\\S+\\s+)?(?:kernel: \\[ *\\d+\\.\\d+\\]\\s+)?(?:@vserver_\\S+\\s+)?(?:(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?(auth|dovecot(-auth)?|auth-worker)(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?(auth|dovecot(-auth)?|auth-worker)(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)\\s+)?(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\]\\s+)?(auth|auth-worker\\(\\d+\\)): Info: sql\\(\\S*,<HOST>\\): Password mismatch\\s*$']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,419 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'addjournalmatch', '_SYSTEMD_UNIT=dovecot.service']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,419 fail2ban.filtersystemd  [4080]: INFO    Added journal match for: '_SYSTEMD_UNIT=dovecot.service'
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,420 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'addaction', 'firewallcmd-ipset']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,420 fail2ban.CommandAction  [4080]: DEBUG   Set action firewallcmd-ipset timeout = 60
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,420 fail2ban.CommandAction  [4080]: DEBUG   Set actionstart = 
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,420 fail2ban.CommandAction  [4080]: DEBUG   Set actionban = 
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,420 fail2ban.CommandAction  [4080]: DEBUG   Set actionunban = 
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,420 fail2ban.CommandAction  [4080]: DEBUG   Set actioncheck = 
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,420 fail2ban.CommandAction  [4080]: DEBUG   Set actionstop = 
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,420 fail2ban.CommandAction  [4080]: DEBUG   Created <class 'fail2ban.server.action.CommandAction'>
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,421 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'actionban', 'ipset add fail2ban-<name> <ip> timeout <bantime> -exist']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,421 fail2ban.CommandAction  [4080]: DEBUG   Set actionban = ipset add fail2ban-<name> <ip> timeout <bantime> -exist
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,422 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'actionstop', 'firewall-cmd --direct --remove-rule ipv4 filter <chain> 0 -p <protocol> -m multiport --dports <port> -m set --match-set fail2ban-<name> src -j <blocktype>\nipset flush fail2ban-<name>\nipset destroy fail2ban-<name>']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,422 fail2ban.CommandAction  [4080]: DEBUG   Set actionstop = firewall-cmd --direct --remove-rule ipv4 filter <chain> 0 -p <protocol> -m multiport --dports <port> -m set --match-set fail2ban-<name> src -j <blocktype>
    ipset flush fail2ban-<name>
    ipset destroy fail2ban-<name>
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,422 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'actionstart', 'ipset create fail2ban-<name> hash:ip timeout <bantime>\nfirewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter <chain> 0 -p <protocol> -m multiport --dports <port> -m set --match-set fail2ban-<name> src -j <blocktype>']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,422 fail2ban.CommandAction  [4080]: DEBUG   Set actionstart = ipset create fail2ban-<name> hash:ip timeout <bantime>
    firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter <chain> 0 -p <protocol> -m multiport --dports <port> -m set --match-set fail2ban-<name> src -j <blocktype>
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,423 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'actionunban', 'ipset del fail2ban-<name> <ip> -exist']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,423 fail2ban.CommandAction  [4080]: DEBUG   Set actionunban = ipset del fail2ban-<name> <ip> -exist
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,424 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'protocol', 'tcp']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,424 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'chain', 'INPUT']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,424 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'lockingopt', '-w']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,425 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'known/known/name', 'default']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,425 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'blocktype', 'REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,426 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'known/lockingopt', '-w']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,427 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'known/known/port', 'ssh']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,427 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'known/protocol', 'tcp']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,428 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'known/known/lockingopt', '-w']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,428 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'port', 'pop3,pop3s,imap,imaps,submission,465,sieve']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,429 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'known/known/chain', 'INPUT']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,429 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'known/name', 'default']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,430 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'known/known/protocol', 'tcp']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,430 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'known/bantime', '600']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,431 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'bantime', '60000']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,431 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'iptables', 'iptables <lockingopt>']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,432 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'known/__name__', 'Init']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,432 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'returntype', 'RETURN']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,432 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'known/returntype', 'RETURN']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,433 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'known/known/__name__', 'Init']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,433 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'known/known/returntype', 'RETURN']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,434 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'name', 'dovecot']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,434 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'known/known/blocktype', 'REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,435 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'known/port', 'ssh']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,435 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'known/iptables', 'iptables <lockingopt>']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,435 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'known/chain', 'INPUT_direct']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,436 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'known/blocktype', 'REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,437 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['set', 'dovecot', 'action', 'firewallcmd-ipset', 'known/known/iptables', 'iptables <lockingopt>']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,437 fail2ban.transmitter    [4080]: DEBUG   Command: ['start', 'dovecot']
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,439 fail2ban.filtersystemd  [4080]: DEBUG   Read systemd journal entry: u'2016-12-09T21:16:01.423994 xxx.xxx.com dovecot[1513]: doveconf: Warning: NOTE: You can get a new clean config file with: doveconf -n > dovecot-new.conf'
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,441 fail2ban.filtersystemd  [4080]: DEBUG   Read systemd journal entry: u"2016-12-09T21:16:01.424219 xxx.xxx.com dovecot[1513]: doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:1: 'imaps' protocol is no longer necessary, remove it"
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,442 fail2ban.jail           [4080]: INFO    Jail 'dovecot' started
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,444 fail2ban.action         [4080]: DEBUG   ipset create fail2ban-dovecot hash:ip timeout 60000
    firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports pop3,pop3s,imap,imaps,submission,465,sieve -m set --match-set fail2ban-dovecot src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,748 fail2ban.action         [4080]: DEBUG   ipset create fail2ban-dovecot hash:ip timeout 60000
    firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports pop3,pop3s,imap,imaps,submission,465,sieve -m set --match-set fail2ban-dovecot src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable -- stdout: 'success\n'
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,749 fail2ban.action         [4080]: DEBUG   ipset create fail2ban-dovecot hash:ip timeout 60000
    firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports pop3,pop3s,imap,imaps,submission,465,sieve -m set --match-set fail2ban-dovecot src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable -- stderr: ''
    2016-12-09 21:29:29,749 fail2ban.action         [4080]: DEBUG   ipset create fail2ban-dovecot hash:ip timeout 60000
    firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports pop3,pop3s,imap,imaps,submission,465,sieve -m set --match-set fail2ban-dovecot src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable -- returned successfully
```

/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf

```
    [INCLUDES]
    before = paths-fedora.conf

    [DEFAULT]
    ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8
    ignorecommand =
    bantime  = 600
    findtime  = 600
    maxretry = 5
    backend = systemd
    usedns = warn
    logencoding = auto
    enabled = false
    filter = %(__name__)s

    #
    # ACTIONS
    #
    destemail = root@localhost
    sender = root@localhost
    mta = sendmail
    protocol = tcp
    chain = INPUT
    port = 0:65535
    fail2ban_agent = Fail2Ban/%(fail2ban_version)s

    banaction = firewallcmd-ipset
    banaction_allports = firewallcmd-allports


    # The simplest action to take: ban only
    action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, bantime="%(bantime)s", port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]

    # ban & send an e-mail with whois report to the destemail.
    action_mw = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, bantime="%(bantime)s", port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
                %(mta)s-whois[name=%(__name__)s, sender="%(sender)s", dest="%(destemail)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]

    # ban & send an e-mail with whois report and relevant log lines
    # to the destemail.
    action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, bantime="%(bantime)s", port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
                 %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, sender="%(sender)s", dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s"]

    # See the IMPORTANT note in action.d/xarf-login-attack for when to use this action
    #
    # ban & send a xarf e-mail to abuse contact of IP address and include relevant log lines
    # to the destemail.
    action_xarf = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, bantime="%(bantime)s", port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
                 xarf-login-attack[service=%(__name__)s, sender="%(sender)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, port="%(port)s"]

    # ban IP on CloudFlare & send an e-mail with whois report and relevant log lines
    # to the destemail.
    action_cf_mwl = cloudflare[cfuser="%(cfemail)s", cftoken="%(cfapikey)s"]
                    %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, sender="%(sender)s", dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s"]


    action_badips = badips.py[category="%(__name__)s", banaction="%(banaction)s", agent="%(fail2ban_agent)s"]
    action_badips_report = badips[category="%(__name__)s", agent="%(fail2ban_agent)s"]
    action = %(action_)s

    # JAILS

    [dovecot]
    enabled = true
    port    = pop3,pop3s,imap,imaps,submission,465,sieve
    filter = dovecot
    logpath = /var/log/dovecot.log
    maxretry = 1
    findtime = 60000
    bantime = 60000
    datepattern = %b %d %H:%M:%S
    backend = %(dovecot_backend)s
```

etc/fail2ban/filter.d/dovecot.conf

```
    etc/fail2ban/filter.d/dovecot.conf

    # Fail2Ban filter Dovecot authentication and pop3/imap server
    #

    [INCLUDES]

    before = common.conf

    [Definition]

    _daemon = (auth|dovecot(-auth)?|auth-worker)

    failregex =auth-worker\(\S*\): Info: sql\(\S*,<HOST>\): Password mismatch\s*$
               auth-worker\(\S*\): Info: sql\(\S*,<HOST>\): unknown user\s*$           


    ignoreregex = 

    [Init]

    journalmatch = _SYSTEMD_UNIT=dovecot.service
```

/etc/fail2ban/jail.d/00-firewalld.conf

```
[DEFAULT]
banaction = firewallcmd-ipset
```

Testing:
fail2ban-regex /var/log/dovecot.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/dovecot.conf  --print-all-matched

```
    Running tests
    =============

    Use   failregex filter file : dovecot, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
    Use         log file : /var/log/dovecot.log
    Use         encoding : UTF-8


    Results
    =======
    Failregex: 11 total
    |-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
    |   1) [10] auth-worker\(\S*\): Info: sql\(\S*,<HOST>\): Password mismatch\s*$
    |   2) [1] auth-worker\(\S*\): Info: sql\(\S*,<HOST>\): unknown user\s*$
    `-

    Ignoreregex: 0 total

    Date template hits:
    |- [# of hits] date format
    |  [24] (?:DAY )?MON Day 24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Year)?
    `-

    Lines: 24 lines, 0 ignored, 11 matched, 13 missed
    [processed in 0.01 sec]

    |- Matched line(s):
    |  Dec 09 13:21:24 auth-worker(30106): Info: sql(user2@test.example.com,192.168.13.107): Password mismatch
    |  Dec 09 13:21:34 auth-worker(30106): Info: sql(user2@test.example.com,192.168.13.107): Password mismatch
    |  Dec 09 14:16:13 auth-worker(31603): Info: sql(user2@test.example.coml,192.168.13.107): unknown user
    |  Dec 09 20:37:39 auth-worker(11941): Info: sql(user2@test.example.com,172.16.2.10): Password mismatch
    |  Dec 09 20:37:47 auth-worker(11941): Info: sql(user2@test.example.com,172.16.2.10): Password mismatch
    |  Dec 09 20:37:53 auth-worker(11941): Info: sql(user2@test.example.com,172.16.2.10): Password mismatch
    |  Dec 09 20:37:56 auth-worker(11941): Info: sql(user2@test.example.com,172.16.2.10): Password mismatch
    |  Dec 09 20:37:59 auth-worker(11941): Info: sql(user2@test.example.com,172.16.2.10): Password mismatch
    |  Dec 09 21:29:57 auth-worker(4141): Info: sql(user2@test.example.com,172.16.2.10): Password mismatch
    |  Dec 09 21:30:04 auth-worker(4141): Info: sql(user2@test.example.com,172.16.2.10): Password mismatch
    |  Dec 09 21:30:11 auth-worker(4141): Info: sql(user2@test.example.com,172.16.2.10): Password mismatch
    `-
    |- Missed line(s):
    |  Dec 09 14:16:19 auth-worker(31603): Info: sql(user2@test.example.coml,192.168.13.107): unknown userDec 09 20:37:06 config: Warning: NOTE: You can get a new clean config file with: doveconf -n > dovecot-new.conf
    |  Dec 09 20:37:06 config: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:1: 'imaps' protocol is no longer necessary, remove it
    |  Dec 09 20:37:09 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<user2@test.example.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=172.16.2.10, lip=10.8.8.59, mpid=11944, TLS, session=<nQg+4T5DvQCsEAIK>
    |  Dec 09 20:37:09 imap(user2@test.example.com): Info: Disconnected: Disconnected in IDLE in=11 out=366
    |  Dec 09 20:38:41 imap-login: Info: Disconnected (auth failed, 5 attempts in 62 secs): user=<user2@test.example.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=172.16.2.10, lip=10.8.8.59, TLS: Disconnected, session=<4akO4z5DxACsEAIK>
    |  Dec 09 21:15:26 anvil: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
    |  Dec 09 21:15:26 log: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
    |  Dec 09 21:15:26 master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
    |  Dec 09 21:16:01 master: Info: Dovecot v2.2.10 starting up for imap, lmtp (core dumps disabled)
    |  Dec 09 21:29:41 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<user2@test.example.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=172.16.2.10, lip=10.8.8.59, mpid=4144, TLS, session=<ehkWnT9DVQCsEAIK>
    |  Dec 09 21:29:42 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<user2@test.example.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=172.16.2.10, lip=10.8.8.59, mpid=4145, TLS, session=<59krnT9DVACsEAIK>
    |  Dec 09 21:30:21 imap(user2@test.example.com): Info: Disconnected: Logged out in=1716 out=12112
    |  Dec 09 21:32:48 imap-login: Info: Disconnected (auth failed, 3 attempts in 171 secs): user=<user2@test.example.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=172.16.2.10, lip=10.8.8.59, TLS: Disconnected, session=<QIYQnj9DVwCsEAIK>
```

dovecot.log

```
Dec 09 13:21:24 auth-worker(30106): Info: sql(user2@test.example.com,192.168.13.107): Password mismatch
Dec 09 13:21:34 auth-worker(30106): Info: sql(user2@test.example.com,192.168.13.107): Password mismatch
Dec 09 14:16:13 auth-worker(31603): Info: sql(user@test.example.com,192.168.13.107): unknown user
```

Comment: Ok everything is working after changing:

Answer (score 1):

Ok, everything is working, after changing a line in file:  /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf
in [dovecot] section:

backend = %(dovecot_backend)s
to
backend = pooling

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted so that the question will not keep reappearing on the open question list.

Comment: ok, but if this is working, then why?

Comment: also perhaps the backend should be polling and not pooling? I tried to suggest an edit, but it's less than six characters